# Are ActiveRecord dynamic attribute-based finders thread-safe?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

according to [this](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/five_activerecord_tips) (older) post these Rails 3 finders have race conditions. Something like

```
 User.find_or_create_by_username(:username => 'uuu', :password => 'xxx')
```

could possibly create two records under some conditions according to the post.

Is this still relevant for Rails 3.0+ ? Thanks

Comment: And one more question - exclamation mark versions are not possible. Is there a trick to force these to report errors upon creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. In the amount of time the first statement is executed and the object created, a second statement can be executed in parallel.
There's no exclusive lock.

The best way to prevent this is to add an unique validation in your model and an unique index in your database. In this way, the database will raise an error if you try to create two records with the same fields.

Comment: Thanks. I thought they changed it since the active_record/dynamic_finder_match.rb is new.